# Spark: how does partitionBy (DataFrameWriter) actually work?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I've been using `partitionBy` but I don't quite get why we should use this.

I have a csv record like this :

```
--------------------------- ---------
name | age | entranceDate | dropDate |
--------------------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
Mary | 15  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
```

What would happen if I use :

```
String[] partitions =
new String[] {
  "name",
  "entranceDate"
};

df.write()
.partitionBy(partitions)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.parquet(parquetPath);
```

And what if I partition on `null` column :

```
String[] partitions =
new String[] {
  "name",
  "dropDate"
};

df.write()
.partitionBy(partitions)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.parquet(parquetPath);
```

Could anyone explain how it works ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of df.write.partitionBy works as follows:

> - For every partition of the dataframe, get the unique values of the columns in partitionBy argument
> - Write the data for every unique combination in a different file

In your example above, let us say your dataframe has 10 partitions. Let us assume that partitions 1-5 have 5 unique combinations of name and entrance date, partitions 6-10 have 10 unique combination of name and entrance date. Each combination of name and entrance date will be written as a different file. Thus partitions 1-5 each will be written to 5 files and partitions 6-10, each will be split-ted in  10 files. The total number of files generated by the write operation will be 5*5 + 5*10 = 75. partitionBy looks at the unique values of the combination of columns. From the documentation of the api:

> Partitions the output by the given columns on the file system. If
>   specified, the output is laid out on the file system similar to Hive's
>   partitioning scheme. As an example, when we partition a dataset by
>   year and then month, the directory layout would look like:
>   - year=2016/month=01/ - year=2016/month=02/
>
> Partitioning is one of the most widely used techniques to optimize
>   physical data layout. It provides a coarse-grained index for skipping
>   unnecessary data reads when queries have predicates on the partitioned
>   columns. In order for partitioning to work well, the number of
>   distinct values in each column should typically be less than tens of
>   thousands.
>
> This is applicable for all file-based data sources (e.g. Parquet,
>   JSON) starting with Spark 2.1.0.

A one of the columns in the partitionBy clause has a same value for all rows, then the data will be split based on the values of the other columns in the partitionBy argument.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for you explanation ! When I look into the directory it generates, if I do sqlContext.read.parquet("/name=Tom/entraceDate=2019-10-01/parquet1.gz.parquet") it shows both two columns "name" and "entraceDate", but if I do sqlContext.read.parquet("/name=Tom/entraceDate=2019-10-01"), the column "name" is no longer shown. Why ?

Comment: Because in Hive, partitioning columns are **pseudo-columns** >> they are actually _metadata_ (defined by the directory in which files are located), and not _data_ (not present in the files).

Answer (score 1):

DataFrameWriter's partitionBy takes **independently** current DataFrame partitions and writes **each** partition splitted by the unique values of the columns passed.

Let's take your example and assume that we already have two DF partitions and we want to `partitionBy()` only with one column - `name`.

Partition 1

```
--------------------------- ---------
name | age | entranceDate | dropDate |
--------------------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
Mary | 15  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
Tom  | 15  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
```

Partition 2

```
--------------------------- ---------
name | age | entranceDate | dropDate |
--------------------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
Tom | 15  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
Tom  | 15  | 2019-10-01   | null     |
--------------------------------------
```

In this case **three** files would be created. Two files for first partition, one for Tom, one for Mary, and one file for second partition - cause there is only Tom data there.

In case of several columns partitionBy() takes the combination of values.

Comment: Thank you, now my problem is that I get directory /name=Tom/entraceDate=2019-10-01/, but when I read from parquet, the "name" column is no longer there